# animation for several CClabelTTF

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Did the animation for CCLabelTTF, which is triggered by pressing a button. But if I use this animation for some CCLabelTTF, the animation is applied only to the latter. What is wrong?

```
        id scaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.4 scale:0.5];
        id scaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.5];
        id scaleBack = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.0];
        id combination = [CCSequence actions:scaleDown, scaleUp, scaleBack, nil];
        id repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:combination times:3];
        [Var1Podpis,Var2Podpis,Var3Podpis runAction:repeat];
```

Answer (score 3):

actions cant be concurrently on multiple targets ... they contain state about a specific target. You should put all your code to create repeat in a method, and run it once per target.

```
-(CCAction*) pulseAction {
    id scaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.4 scale:0.5];
    id scaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.5];
    id scaleBack = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.0];
    id combination = [CCSequence actions:scaleDown, scaleUp, scaleBack, nil];
    id repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:combination times:3];
    return repeat;
}

and then 

[Var1Podpis runAction:[self pulseAction]];
[Var2Podpis runAction:[self pulseAction]];
[Var3Podpis runAction:[self pulseAction]];
```

or something similar. Not tested, from memory.

Comment: I fixed a few missing brackets and gave your method a bit more useful name! :P

Comment: working with a good IDE is a b.... it does pretty much all the bracketing for me and i tend to f'get about them. As for useful, famous last quotes "one guy's object is another guy's belly laugh"  :)

Comment: @JamesWebster ... ps. Love your gran :)

Comment: yep ... kind of addictive ... a good thing in the freemium business.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the action and run it on your three separate targets.

```
id scaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.4 scale:0.5];
id scaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.5];
id scaleBack = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.0];
id combination = [CCSequence actions:scaleDown, scaleUp, scaleBack, nil];
id repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:combination times:3];

[var1Podpis runAction:[repeat copy]];
[var2Podpis runAction:[repeat copy]];
[var3Podpis runAction:[repeat copy]];
```

<sub>NB: It's convention to give instanceVariablesTitleCaseNames, i.e. starting with a lowercase char.</sub>

Comment: yep, just another way to skin the same cat. However, i find that i eventually have to do these 'standard animation sequence' from different places in my controller, ie the local ivar is not present everywhere, thus the extra 'load' of messaging to a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void) pulseActionForItem:(CCNode*) item {
        id scaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.4 scale:0.5];
        id scaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.5];
        id scaleBack = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:.2 scale:1.0];
        id combination = [CCSequence actions:scaleDown, scaleUp, scaleBack, nil];
        id repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:combination times:3];
        [item runAction:repeat];
    }
```

[self pulseActionForItem:Var1Podpis];
....